# IOS9 UTF-8 line break

Tags: ios, csv, utf-8, xcode7

Is there a way to add a line break to a CSV file? My app loads the cvs file to display the data in a table view and search. Any idea? I need a line break or any kind of text separator to show more results in the same page. Any help is more than welcome :)

Comment: If you double-quote the field, some dialects of CSV allow newlines in the field value. You're not showing any code so we can only speculate whether this works in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add **/n** into the results.

```
let resultsArray = ["1","2"]
for str in resultsArray {
   cell.text = str + "/n" 
}
```

----------------Update-----------------------

You can convert CSV file into sqlite, then to read it. I did it before, Just FYI:

```
sqlite> create table foo(a, b);
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import test.csv foo
```